# set value to hidden input

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong. The hiddenvalue is being kept all the time null without any value assigned to it.

The following is the code;

**Javacript**

This is intended to occur on a click event on a map

```
var str = "ryan";
document.getElementById("hiddenvalue").value = str;
```

This is from the asp.net

```html
<div>
    <input id="hiddenvalue" type="hidden" value="" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

And this is how am I referring to it from the codebehind:

```c#
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into altitude select nextval('altitude_id_seq'), :value", conn)) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("value", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = hiddenvalue.Value; 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For some reason no value is being set. Can anyone guide since I have been for hours trying to debug this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access the `hiddenvalue` on code behind then its a server side control, you need to access it with `ClientID` in Javascript

```
document.getElementById("<%= hiddenvalue.ClientID %>").value = str;
```

Or you may sepcify [`ClientIDMode Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) *(static)* with `hiddenvalue`